# Error: difference between perror and fprintf

Tags: c, malloc

Any difference between the following two approaches when encountering and error?

```
if (!mallocd_buffer) {

    // this?
    fprintf(stderr,"malloc() failed in file %s at line # %d", __FILE__, __LINE__);

    // or this?
    perror("Failed to copy a string\n\n\n\n\n");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: `malloc()` does not set `errno`, so `perror()` would be incorrect.

Comment: And if you had called a system call that did set `errno`, your `fprintf()` would be incomplete and useless without the value of `errno` or the output of `strerror()`.

Comment: @user207421: Standard C does not require `malloc()` to set `errno`; the POSIX specification for [`malloc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html) does — but carefully marks that requirement as an extension over standard C.  OTOH, the only documented reason for `malloc()` failing is `ENOMEM` — so it isn't all that informative.

Comment: Not the `\n\n\n\n` in `perror` - `perror' will output the *message* followed by `:` and the description of the error, followed by newline, so the output would look rather silly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `perror`, you get the system error message implied by the current value of `errno` in the output, after the string you supply as the argument.

Using `fprintf(stderr, "…", …)`, you're in complete control of the formatting.

I rarely use `perror()`; it doesn't meet my requirements as formatting the string to pass to it is fiddly.  I use the functions I wrote such as `err_syserr()` — code which is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

On BSD, there is a similar package called `err(3)`; you can find it on Linux too (see [`err(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/err.3.html)).  You will probably prefer to use that over my code, if only because the system functions manage to be privy to the value of `argv[0]` indirectly, whereas my code isn't because there isn't a portable interface to gain access to `argv[0]` except via the arguments to `main()`) and my code therefore relies on you calling `err_setarg0(argv[0])` in `main()` to set the program name.